# Cakephp Countercache - Logical issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

I am using Cakephp 2.0 My model relationship as follows:

> **User has many Post**
>
> **Post has many Comment**
>
> **Post has many Like**
>
> **Comment has many Like**

In Post table I added a column "like_count" and enable the countercache 
and 
In Comment table I added a column "like_count" and enable the countercache

Likes table contain:

id,post_id,comment_idu,user_id

and Model as follows :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'counterCache' => true
    ),
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'comment_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'counterCache' => true
    ))
```

Its working Fine..

> But Now I need to do total like count(Post like count + Comment like
>   count) for each user. so I planned to add a field in users table and
>   enable the countercache But totally strucked.. what will be the column
>   name i need to add in users table and where i need to put Countercache
>   => true. I dont how to go further..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your $belongsTo array.

```
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'counterCache' => true
    ),
```

And you'll add a `like_count` column in the `users` table.

---

And in your `UserModel` you'll need to add a HasMany for likes of course.